# Installing Windows 7 on iMac

Tags: windows-7, mac, osx-yosemite, imac

I want to install Windows 7 on an iMac and was wondering if this could cause any complications with my programs and any future work? I mainly work with C++, OpenGL and glsl.

Full specs of the iMac: iMac: 3.2 GHz (Core i5, Late 2013) iMac Intel 27" OS: OS X Yosemite Processor: 3.2 GHz intel i5 Ram: GB 1600 MHz DDR3 Graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 755M 1024 MB

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems if you use Bootcamp and don't forget to install the drivers from the Bootcamp installation media...

Comment: Exactly like @Big Chris says. virtually +1 :) Consider to write it as an aswer? This link may be helpfull https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202008

Answer (score 0):

As your iMac is an Intel-based computer you should have no problem installing (using Bootcamp) and using Windows 7 (including your programming softwares).

Don't forget to use the Bootcamp installer to make a drivers disk so that Windows is able to install the iMac devices.